# Pandas. Найти среднее из диапазона следующих значений в столбце

Tags: python, циклы, pandas

Весь вопрос состоит в том, чтобы вычислить среднее значение следующих n строк в n столбце относительно текущего элемента, т.е `1 => mean([2, 3, 4]); 2 => mean([3, 4, 5])`.

Простой тестовый датафрейм с одной колонкой:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: range(20)})
```

И есть решение к моему вопросу, но как решить его именно средствами pandas?, Такая легкая задача, а что то мозги закипели понимать как устроен весь этот механизм итерирующий в pandas. Поэтому сделал генератор такой:

```
def idx(x, step):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(x) - step):
        result.append(x.shift(-1)[i:i + step].mean())
    return pd.DataFrame(result)

df[2] = idx(df[1], 3)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу: посчитать среднее в плавающем окне (окно начинается со следующего по отношению к текущему элемента) из N элементов:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [56]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(20)})

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
    col1
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    14
15    15
16    16
17    17
18    18
19    19
```

Решение - воспользуемся [Series.rolling()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) + [window.Rolling.mean()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean.html):

```
In [63]: N = 3

In [64]: df['col2'] = df.col1.shift().rolling(N, min_periods=1).mean()

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
    col1  col2
0      0   NaN
1      1   0.0
2      2   0.5
3      3   1.0
4      4   2.0
5      5   3.0
6      6   4.0
7      7   5.0
8      8   6.0
9      9   7.0
10    10   8.0
11    11   9.0
12    12  10.0
13    13  11.0
14    14  12.0
15    15  13.0
16    16  14.0
17    17  15.0
18    18  16.0
19    19  17.0
```

если середина окна должна приходиться на текущий элемент:

```
In [71]: df['col2'] = df.col1.rolling(N, center=True, min_periods=1).mean()

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
    col1  col2
0      0   0.5
1      1   1.0
2      2   2.0
3      3   3.0
4      4   4.0
5      5   5.0
6      6   6.0
7      7   7.0
8      8   8.0
9      9   9.0
10    10  10.0
11    11  11.0
12    12  12.0
13    13  13.0
14    14  14.0
15    15  15.0
16    16  16.0
17    17  17.0
18    18  18.0
19    19  18.5

In [78]: df['col3'] = df.col1.rolling(N, center=True, min_periods=1).mean().values[::-1]

In [79]: df
Out[79]:
    col1  col2  col3
0      0   0.5  18.5
1      1   1.0  18.0
2      2   2.0  17.0
3      3   3.0  16.0
4      4   4.0  15.0
5      5   5.0  14.0
6      6   6.0  13.0
7      7   7.0  12.0
8      8   8.0  11.0
9      9   9.0  10.0
10    10  10.0   9.0
11    11  11.0   8.0
12    12  12.0   7.0
13    13  13.0   6.0
14    14  14.0   5.0
15    15  15.0   4.0
16    16  16.0   3.0
17    17  17.0   2.0
18    18  18.0   1.0
19    19  18.5   0.5
```

Comment: То, что надо! Спасибо вам. Только порядок обратный, но это не проблема.

Comment: @ИльяЛисунов, вы можете пояснить на счет обратного порядка - вы имеете в виду `.shift(-1)`?

Comment: принимать за значения не предыдущие строки, а следующие. Я просто развернул колонку `df.col1[::-1].shift(-1).rolling(N, min_periods=1).mean()` @MaxU

Comment: @ИльяЛисунов, т.е. так как в столбце `col3` в обновленном ответе?

Comment: Почему то не могу через "собаку" уведомить

Comment: Нужный результат получаю при добавлении [::-1] к col1 изначально, в вашем ответе столбец развёрнут после применения rolling

Comment: @ИльяЛисунов, тогда у вас должно получиться тоже что и в `col2` в моем последнем ответе - `df['col2'] = df.col1.rolling(N, center=True, min_periods=1).mean()`, т.е. можно обойтись без `.shift(...)`

Comment: Нет, прошу прощения, нужный результат даст строка `df.col1[::-1].shift().rolling(N, min_periods=1).mean()` @MaxU